# In BigQuery, how to count number of changes on column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to create a column in my BQ table that keeps track of the # of times the value in another column has changed. I have the following table:

```
SELECT 'a' as letter, 'Nick' as name
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 'Nick'
UNION ALL SELECT 'd', 'Nick'
UNION ALL SELECT 't', 'Joe'
UNION ALL SELECT 'u', 'Joe'
UNION ALL SELECT 'n', 'Nick'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'Nick'
UNION ALL SELECT 'z', 'Nick'
UNION ALL SELECT 'p', 'Chris'
UNION ALL SELECT 'm', 'Chris'
UNION ALL SELECT 'n', 'Joe'
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 'Joe'
```

And, starting at 1 and counting upwards, I'd like to count the number of times the `name` column has changed. My objective output is a table like this:

```
letter  name  num 
a   Nick      1
b   Nick      1
d   Nick      1
t   Joe       2
u   Joe       2
n   Nick      3
a   Nick      3
z   Nick      3
p   Chris     4
m   Chris     4
n   Joe       5
b   Joe       5
```

Even though a name repeats, the num column increments as long as the name column is different from the previous row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 pos, 'a' AS letter, 'Nick' AS name UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'b', 'Nick' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'd', 'Nick' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 't', 'Joe' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, 'u', 'Joe' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6, 'n', 'Nick' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7, 'a', 'Nick' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 8, 'z', 'Nick' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 9, 'p', 'Chris' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 10, 'm', 'Chris' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 11, 'n', 'Joe' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 12, 'b', 'Joe'
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(num), 1 + COUNTIF(num) OVER(ORDER BY pos) num
FROM (
  SELECT *, name != LAG(name) OVER(ORDER BY pos) num 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

with result

```
Row pos letter  name    num  
1   1   a       Nick    1    
2   2   b       Nick    1    
3   3   d       Nick    1    
4   4   t       Joe     2    
5   5   u       Joe     2    
6   6   n       Nick    3    
7   7   a       Nick    3    
8   8   z       Nick    3    
9   9   p       Chris   4    
10  10  m       Chris   4    
11  11  n       Joe     5    
12  12  b       Joe     5
```

**Note**: in order to achieve your goal - you **MUST** have column in your table that will define order of the rows  - thus you can see I added column pos. this column can be of any sortable type - usually it is date, timestamp or some id (like orderid), etc.